# append a specific line from a file to a list element with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, append

I retrieve some values from a DB and save them in a file. 
I have a list with an id in every `li` element.

When I click on an element I want to append the line from the file which is equal to the id I just clicked on.

I have an example:

```
 <li id="test1">just test </li>
```

There is a `test1` value in a line in the file. I want to append the value of it when I click on it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


            $.get("serverResource", function(data){
                        $('#test1').click(function()    {
                                   $('#test1').append(data);
                    });
```

The problem is that `data` contains the entire file data and not just a line. How can I get a line from the file and then check the value with the id and if it's true append it?

Comment: Do you have an example of the what the line in the file looks like? And what the data that is returned looks like?

Comment: the data in the file is just text and line1 : test1 , line2:test2 etc...
So when i click on the test li element i want next to the "just test" text to append a "test1" text.

The way i do it when i click on an li element i have all the data of the file appended next to the "just test" text ...

i need smthing to take everyline from the file and compare it with the id so when its true to print just the line...

Answer (score 0):

if your test data looks like this:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

and line X correspondens to li X, then you could read the content of the file you load via AJAX in a javascript array by splitting the lines and then inserting the data like so:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            ...
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {                                 
                    $.get('my_data.txt', function(data) {
                        var lines = data.split("\n");

                        $('#root li').click(function() {
                            var li = $(this);
                            // find position of the li in the containing ul
                            // and append the line to the li
                            var index = $('#root li').index(li);
                            li.append(lines[index]);
                        });
                    });                        
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul id="root">
                <li id="test1">Content 1</li>
                <li id="test2">Content 2</li>
                <li id="test3">Content 3</li>
                <li id="test4">Content 4</li>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This only is a good approach if your data file does not contain hundreds of large and long lines. Reading that much data in a javascript array consumes a lot of memory.

If you have much data, you should use serverside logic to extract the line from the file:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {                                 
                    $('#root li').click(function() {
                        var li = $(this);
                        var index = $('#root li').index(li);

                        // use this ajax request to let PHP fetch the content of that line
                        $.get('fetchline.php', 'index=' + index, function(line) {
                            li.append(line);                    
                        });
                    });                    
                });
            </script>
```

And fetchline.php could look like this (simplified):

```
<?php 
// get the index provided as GET var
$index = intval($_GET['index']);
// read all lines from the data file in an array, not super optimisied, 
// but should do for not too large files
$lines = file('my_data.txt');
// print the line with index = $index
print $lines[$index];
```